# How to delay execution of function in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout, timedelay

could only find JS stuff on this. I just have basic functions that reload page elements and I want to delay them by like 1-2 seconds to wait for http calls to come through. I tried this (imported from rxjs to) but it doesn't work at all

```
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.clearGroups();
      this.prepareRow();
      this.prepareGroups(); 
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: "*to wait for http calls to come through.*" You should probably be using promises and `async`/`await` to ensure these are called after the reload. Otherwise, you get into a dangerous territory when the calls might be out of sync.

Comment: But if you *do* want to use `setTimeout`, you need an arrow function, otherwise the value of `this` will be incorrect.

Comment: You don't want to wait for HTTP calls to come through using `setTimeout()`. There is a reason HTTP calls are asynchronous. Because you don't know when they will respond. If you're using Angular `HttpClient` to make the calls, then you need to place the statements that depend on it inside the subscription. If there are multiple independent calls, use `forkJoin` to combine them. If they are dependent on each other, map them using `switchMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @VLAZ points out, you need a arrow function (to "close over" the correct this-scope, eg.:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   this.clearGroups();
   this.prepareRow();
   this.prepareGroups(); 
}, 2000);
```

I would however suggest that you reconsider your solution, what about the users that has very poor internet connectivity, where the result could take more than 2 seconds "to arrive", and do you want to penalize people with a fast connection to wait the 2 seconds (for the update to appear)?

If your data arrives as a promise, consider using async / await:

```js
await getData();
this.clearGroups();
this.prepareRow();
this.prepareGroups();
```

(please notice that this will only work if done from an `async` function, else use as traditional Promise with `.then(() => ...)`)

or as an Observable:

```js
getData().pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
   this.clearGroups();
   this.prepareRow();
   this.prepareGroups(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Anders, I did solve it with setTimeout however I kep thinking of it and would be super curious of a better solution so I asked another question and would immensely appreciate if you could review it real quick. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852659/how-to-set-page-reload-on-async-operation-angular-typescript-to-await-http-resol