# How to reload page in Angular Typescript to 'await' HTTP calls with BE

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, subscribe

In below code:

1. http call gets multiple orderline's (items) IDs
2. for each of those makes another http call and reserves them.
   I then need to redo the page with those showing up as reserved.

Whith numerous items, the last 3 lines would execute and reload the page before they actually got reserved in the BE so I added that 0.7 sec delay but that's not best practice and I can't figure out how to do it otherwise (switchMap? how)

```
   this.service.getOrderlineId(this.orderlineIds).subscribe((ids: Number[]) => {
      ids.forEach(id => {
        this.currentReservation = {
          orderline: id,
          company: this.currentUser.company_id,
          company_name: this.currentCompany.name,
          user: this.currentUser.user_id,
          delivery_address: this.currentCompany.address
        }
        this.service.createOrderLineReservation(this.currentReservation).subscribe(reservation => {

        })
      })
    })

    setTimeout(() => {                       
      this.clearGroups();
      this.prepareRow();
      this.prepareGroups();
    }, 700);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Rxjs's pipe to manipulate the streams

```js
this.service
  .getOrderlineId(this.orderlineIds)
  .pipe(
    map((ids: number[]) =>
        // Map the ids to an Observable list
      ids.map((id) =>
        this.service.createOrderLineReservation({
          orderline: id,
          company: this.currentUser.company_id,
          company_name: this.currentCompany.name,
          user: this.currentUser.user_id,
          delivery_address: this.currentCompany.address,
        })
      )
    ),
    switchMap((reservations$: Observable[]) => 
    // After all observables emit, emit values as an array
    zip(...reservations$))
  )
  .subscribe((reservations: Reservation[]) => {
      // You get an ordered list of reservations

      this.clearGroups();
      this.prepareRow();
      this.prepareGroups();
  });
```

ps: Don't use setTimout

Comment: Deprecated in favor of static zip.
Just import from 'rxjs' instead of from 'rxjs/operators'.
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip